# How to have different targets for differents directories

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have to directories `/src/server` and `/src/client` for the backend and frontend code.

In the backend I want to target my `.ts` sources to es2017 javascript. In the client I want to target the `.ts` sources to es5. How can I indicate that to the Visual Studio Code?

I try to put two different tsconfig.json in each directory. But the Visual Studio Code only takes the root tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two `tsconfig.json` files, one for client and the other for server and then compile each using `tsc` with `-p` flag, e.g.:

```
tsc -p /src/server && tsc -p /src/client
```

Comment: Yes, You are right!. I have a little different question now, very related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249684/how-to-have-different-libraries-for-differents-directories-in-vsc-for-ts