# How to have different "libraries" for differents directories in VSC for TS

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have two directories `/src/server` and `/src/client` for the backend and frontend code.

My question is about Visual Studio Code and its "error" highlights or underlines.

In the backend I want to target my .ts sources to es2017 javascript, and I want that VSC acts as if I set `"lib": ["es2017"]`. In the client I want to target the .ts sources to es5 and VSC warn as if I set `"lib": ["es2015", "dom"]`. How can I indicate that to the Visual Studio Code?

I try to put two different tsconfig.json in each directory. But the Visual Studio Code only takes the root tsconfig.json.

For compiling I use two separates config.json and I compile it from the command line (as you see at [How to have different targets for differents directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243287/how-to-have-different-targets-for-differents-directories)).

[image: array tsc example]

#### How can I tell VSC that for some directories it has to use some config.json and others for others?

Comment: I just recreated your setup and don't have this problem (i.e. the error is being shown for `es2015` config and not being shown for `es2017` config).

Comment: Here I upload a minimal reproducible example: two two-line ts sources and the tsconfig.json: https://github.com/emilioplatzer/so-53249684

Comment: Why can't you have one `tsconfig.json` in `client` and the other in `server`?

Comment: I try it. It works. I don't know why I need both. This example is simple but If I had many directories and only in one I need different `tsconfig` it is anoying. But works.